# Interchange of differentiation and summation/integration

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, statistics, derivatives, moment-generating-functions

Ross(Probability, 10th Edition) says in Section 7.7 on moment generating functions that they are defined and differentiated as
$$M(t)=E[e^{tx}]\Rightarrow M'(t) = \frac{d}{dt} E[e^{tx}]$$

As explained in the textbook, we can "almost always" interchange the differentiation operators to get:
$$=E \left[\frac{d}{dt}(e^{tx}) \right ]$$

- What is the math/method to justify this.
- What are the exceptions? Where can this not be justified.

Comment: It follows from dominated convergence. You can always do this with moment generating functions

Comment: What is "dominated convergence"? And if you can do this, why does it say "almost always"?